# Ruby request failing with a "\" or a double quote in the request body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, special-characters

I have a ruby request with the route as below:

```
put 'book' => :create_record
```

I pass the required data as part of my request body as below:

```
{
  "BookName": "ABC",
  "BookNumber: "ISBN-13"
}
```

However while testing I noticed that when I pass just a slash i.e. "\" as the book name, the service fails with "unexpected token" error. However when I use it as "A\C", it works. Similar is the case with double quotes. If I just pass a double quote as the book name, it fails with "unexpected token" error. It fails even with I pass even number of double quotes.

Is there any regex expression or something which could help handling these special characters?

Comment: How are you creating the request body? Are you building the JSON yourself or are you using a library?

Comment: Am building it myself.

Comment: Use a JSON library instead. No need to make mistakes that other people have solved

Answer (score 0):

Some special characters need to be escaped with a backslash (`\`) in the JSON request body.
Please note that this is an issue of the client, not your Rails application.

Example for a backslash:

```
{
  "BookName": "\\",
  "BookNumber": "ISBN-13"
}
```

or a double quote:

```
{
  "BookName": "\"",
  "BookNumber": "ISBN-13"
}
```

Comment: Okay. I was trying to handle it in rails app to avoid a failure or crash if my client misses handling it.

Comment: The only way to achieve that is parsing the HTTP request body yourself and implementing a non-standard JSON parser. That's probably not what you want…